# Maximum values from column is not coming while using foreach loop

Tags: linux, foreach, grep, csh

I have two files, pins and Output.csv.

File "pins" contains the below information

```
A
A[0]
A[1]
B[0]
B[1]
C
```

File "Output.csv" contains the below information

```
A,10
A[0],9
A[0],11
A[1],8
B[0],19
B[1],2
B[1],60
C,12
```

I had written a shell script, to get the output like this (Final_output.csv)

```
A,10
A[0],11
A[1],8
B[0],19
B[1],60
C,12
```

```
foreach line1 (`cat pins`)
set final_value = `grep -w $line1 Output.csv | cut -d, -f2 | sort | tail -1`
echo "$line1,$final_value" >> Final_output.csv
end
```

But I am only getting the values of A and C. For A[0], A[1], B[0], B[1] values are not coming. What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Try using something like `grep -f pins Output.csv` to do it more or less in one shot--just grep for each of the pins in the output with one command, rather than looping in the shell and spawning tons of processes.

Comment: But is not giving the Max value for the corresponding pin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `join` to filter the Output file with only the keys in the pins file, then use awk to find the max values:

```
join -t, pins Output.csv | awk -F, '!($1 in max) || $2 > max[$1] {max[$1] = $2} END {for (key in max) print key FS max[key]}'
```

```
A,10
C,12
A[0],11
A[1],8
B[0],19
B[1],60
```

The output will be unordered.

Or do it all in awk

```
awk -F, '
    NR == FNR {pin[$1]; next}
    ($1 in pin) && (!($1 in max) || $2 > max[$1]) {max[$1] = $2}
    END {for (key in max) print key FS max[key]}
' pins Output.csv
```

Comment: Yes, it is working specially the second one. Thank you Sir.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep 'A[0]' ...
```

grep interprets `[...]` expression as regex. From [grep manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions):

> A  bracket  expression is a list of characters enclosed by [ and ].  It
>          matches any single character in that list;

Use `-F` option to disable regex in grep.

As I don't have csh, my solution in bash:

```
cat pins | while IFS= read -r l; do 
     r=$(grep -F "$l" Output.csv | cut -d, -f2 | sort | tail -1)
     echo "$l,$r"
done
```

Or you can for example escape `[` with `\` using `l=$(sed 's/\[/\\[/g' <<<"$l")`.